# How to find that a vector is an eigen-vector of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

\begin{equation}
Y=AX=\begin{pmatrix}
   \frac{4}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} &\frac{1}{5} \\
   \frac{1}{5} & \frac{4}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5}\\
   \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{4}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5}\\
   \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{4}{5} & \frac{4}{5}\\
   \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 4 & 0  \\
   1 & 3 & 1 \\
   2 & 2 & 3\\
   3 & 1 & 1 \\
   4 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
   2 & 4,4 & 1 \\
   2,6 & 3,8 & 1,6 \\
   3,2 & 3,2 & 2,8\\
   3,8 & 2,6 & 1,6 \\
   4,4 & 2 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Then I had to do

\begin{equation}
Z=\frac{1}{n}Y^TY=\frac{1}{5}
\begin{pmatrix}
   54,8 & 63,2 & 25,6 \\
   63,2 & 54,8 & 25,6 \\
   25,6 & 25,6 & 14,96
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

And here I had to show that$u_2=
\begin{pmatrix}
   0 \\
   0 \\
   1
\end{pmatrix}$
was an eigen vector of Z. But it doesn't work because it gives

$Z\begin{pmatrix}
   0 \\
   0 \\
   1
\end{pmatrix}
=\frac{1}{5}\begin{pmatrix}
 25,6 \\
25,6 \\
14,96
\end{pmatrix}$

Did I did a mistake or does it reveals that I don't know how to compute eigen vectors?

Comment: Assuming you calculated $Z$ correctly, the you are indeed correct that the given vector is not an eigenvector (this is easy to see directly, as it will only be an eigenvector for lower triangular matrices).

Comment: $(0,0,1)$ is not an eigenvector of $Z$. Is it possible that you were asked to show that it is NOT an eigenvector?

Comment: God, I must have done a mistake, It was asked to "find that $u_2$" is an eigen-vector... I'm trying ro recalculate the whole thing